# Split DataLoader PyTorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, dataloader

Is it possible to split a dataloader object of training dataset into training and validation dataloader?

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import datasets, transforms

train_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(train_data_directory, transform=transforms.ToTensor())
# Data loader
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=100, shuffle=True)
```

Now I would like to split a train_loader to train and validation dataloader.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at `random_split` in [`torch.utils.data`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html). It will handle a random *`Dataset`* split (you have to split before creating the `DataLoader`, not after).

Comment: @RajendraSapkota If this answers your question then please mark the question as accepted.